# Android Power Usage thread in SO?

Tags: discussion

Android Enthusiasts states that "For Enthusiasts and Power Users of Android Operating System".

I wonder is there any Android Tips & Tricks threads in Android Enthusiasts SO?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so; such questions are broad, open ended and don't have a definitive best answer. Therefore, [they're not a good fit for Stack Exchange's Q&A format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/295232). See also the Help Center article [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Older Stack Exchange might still have some of these questions, but they're often locked and they're just kept for reference and not for maintenance.

Comment: Also, even if there still are on other SE sites, they are more of an exception than a norm (like [big list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) questions on Math.SE).